# synchronize vs upload (for backing up to a webdav server)

Tags: cyberduck

I want to back up a large directory (100+ G, thousands++ of files) to an external server using a WebDAV upload (I used to use rsync for this in the past, but the WebDAV host recommends the `duck` CLI tool.

I'm currently using `duck` with the `--existing upload --synchronize` options. In the past, I've used `rsync` with the `--delete` option, because if I delete something on my machine I generally want to delete it on the remote backup as well (I have a separate Time Machine backup for when I really need to retrieve deleted things, anyway).

Is there a way to get `duck` to have the same behaviour? Or am I trying to do it wrong?

Comment: I would recommend the `--upload` command if you only want to backup to the remote host and do not need to download files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to delete files using the synchronization feature. There is an enhancement request for this in ticket [#222](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/222).

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks.